# Understanding the descriptor example from "descriptors howto" article

Tags: python, descriptor, python-descriptors

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of descriptors and I have had no success lately. This [article](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) of descriptor How to has really helped and at the same time it has also confused me. I am struggling with this example here
on why `m.x` calls `def __get__(self, obj, objtype):`

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
```

I believe the reason i am struggling with this is because I am confused by the following statement in the article

> The details of invocation depend on whether obj is an object or a
>   class. For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()`
>   which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.
>   The implementation works through a precedence chain that gives data
>   descriptors priority over instance variables, instance variables
>   priority over non-data descriptors, and assigns lowest priority to
>   `__getattr__()` if provided

I am not sure what the author means here by object or class. Does object mean an instance of a class ? I understand that when we do `instance.var` python internally does a `instance.__dict__["var"]` if that is not found then it does `class.__dict__["var"]`. I kind of lost it after that concept. Could anyone explain a little on how this example is working. How is the definition `def __get__(self, obj, objtype):` being called with `m.x`. I would be very grateful if anyone could clear this up.

Comment: If you use the parameter names:  `def __get__(self, instance, owner)` it might be clearer. `RevealAccess` is a descriptor class and `MyClass` is the owner class.  Bear in mind that classes are objects, so `owner` will be the class object `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by *object* the author means an instance, not a class. The distinction comes from where the descriptor lives; the descriptor is defined on the class, so when accessing that descriptor *directly on the class* a different path is followed from when you access that descriptor on an instance of the class.

In your example, `m` is an instance. That instance itself has no attribute `m` (`'x' in m.__dict__` is `False`). Python also looks at `type(m)` to resolve that attribute, and `type(m)` here is `MyClass`. `'x' in MyClass.__dict__` is `True`, and `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__get__` exists, so Python now knows that that object is a descriptor.

So, because there is no `m.__dict__['x']`, but there *is* a `type(m).__dict__['x'].__get__`, that method is called with `m` and `type(m)` as arguments, leading to `type(m).__dict__['x'].__get__(m, type(m))`.

If `'x' in MyClass.__dict__` is true but `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__get__` did *not* exist (so that object is *not* a descriptor object), then `MyClass.__dict__['x']` would have been returned directly.

The situation gets more interesting if you tried to add the `x` attribute to the instance *too*. In that case it matters if `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__set__` or `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__delete__` exist, making the descriptor a *data* descriptor. Data descriptors always win in the case of a tie. So *if* `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__get__` and *at least one of* `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__set__` or `MyClass.__dict__['x'].__delete__` exist, it doesn't matter anymore if `m.__dict__['x']` also exists. Python won't even look for it.

However, if there are no `__set__` or `__delete__` methods on the descriptor object on the class, then `m.__dict__['x']` wins and is returned. In that case the descriptor is a regular, non-data descriptor and it loses out to the instance attribute.

Last but not least, if `'x' in type(m).__dict__` is false (there is no object on the class), then `m.__dict__['m']` is returned. The descriptor protocol is only applied to objects found on the class, never to attributes on the instance.

Comment: Could you also explain what would have happened if x was an instance variable in `MyClass`rather than a class variable ? (i.e) `if m ('x' in m.__dict__ is True).`

Comment: @JamesFranco: *in addition* to `MyClass.x` existing?

Comment: No if `MyClass.x` did not exist and instead if it was `InstanceOfMyClass.x` (i.e) if x was declared in the `init` method as `self.x`.

Comment: @JamesFranco: in that case there is no conflict. Descriptors are only supported no the class, not the instance, so `m.__dict__['x']` is returned directly.

Comment: Now I think I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Does object mean an instance of a class ?

Yes.

> How is the definition `def __get__(self, obj, objtype):` being called with `m.x`.

Because of just what the documentation you quoted says:

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.

`object.__getattribute__` is mechanism that implements what happens when you do something like `m.x`.  So, explicitly:

```
m.x
type(m).__dict__['x'].__get__(m, type(m))
MyClass.__dict__['x'].__get__(m, MyClass)
RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"').__get__(m, MyClass)
```

so the last line calls the `__get__` method of the `RevealAccess` class.